# Compiler Tokenizer implementation in C#

Tags: c#, compiler, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a compiler for a couple of months now, this is the tokenization part of the lexer.

I would like a code review to improve my coding style and learn new techniques to pretty up my code and make it easier to maintain.

Also because I did not actually study compiler design, I do not know if the structure makes sense at all, so feel free to give any kind of criticism.

This class is a compiler instance, today I will only discuss the tokenization part of it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ShirLanguageCompiler
{
    public class ShirEnvironment
    {
        public ShirEnvironment(string inputpath)
        {
            this.code = File.ReadAllText(inputpath);

            Console.WriteLine("Starting tokenizer");
            this.Tokenizer = new Tokenizer(this);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting parser");
            this.Parser = new Parser(this);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Compiling Environment");
            this.Factory = new ILFactory(this);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Virtual Machine");
            this.VirtualMachine = new VM(this);
        }


        public void Compile()
        {
            Tokenizer.Tokenize();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Tokens));
            Parser.Parse();
            Debug.Assert(Tokenizer.AsCode() == code);
            Factory.Generate();
            VirtualMachine.Execute();
        }

        public Tokenizer Tokenizer;
        public Parser Parser;
        public ILFactory Factory;
        public VM VirtualMachine;

        public ILEnv Intermidiate = new ILEnv();
        public List<Token> Tokens = new List<Token>();
        public List<SyntaxNode> Nodes = new List<SyntaxNode>();

        public ProgramNode Program = new ProgramNode();
        public string code;
    }
}
```

The Tokenizer:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ShirLanguageCompiler
{
    public class Tokenizer
    {
        public Tokenizer(ShirEnvironment _env)
        {
            this.env = _env;
        }

        ShirEnvironment env;

        int cursor;
        int line = 0, col = 0;


        private readonly Dictionary<string, Regex> Patterns = new Dictionary<string, Regex>()
        {
            {"CharPattern",     new Regex("[\\$a-zA-Z]")},
            {"StringPattern",   new Regex("[^\"]")      },
            {"NumCharPattern",  new Regex("[[0-9a-zA-Z]")},
            {"NumberPattern",   new Regex("[0-9\\.]")   }
        };


        private static readonly Dictionary<string, SyntaxKind> Keywords = new Dictionary<string, SyntaxKind>()
        {
            {"True",    SyntaxKind.LiteralTrueKeyword   },
            {"False",   SyntaxKind.LiteralFalseKeyword  },
            {"ref",     SyntaxKind.RefKeyword           },
            {"val",     SyntaxKind.ValKeyword           },
            {"return",  SyntaxKind.ReturnKeyword        },
            {"bind",    SyntaxKind.BindKeyword          },
            {"boolean", SyntaxKind.BooleanKeyword       },
            {"number",  SyntaxKind.NumberKeyword        },
            {"letter",  SyntaxKind.LetterKeyword        },
            {"string",  SyntaxKind.StringKeyword        }
        };


        private static readonly Dictionary<SyntaxKind, Regex> Definitions = new Dictionary<SyntaxKind, Regex>()
        {
            { SyntaxKind.ColonToken,                 new Regex(":")             },
            { SyntaxKind.SemiColonToken,            new Regex(";")             },
            { SyntaxKind.AssignmentToken,            new Regex("=>")         },
            { SyntaxKind.AccessorToken,             new Regex("->")         },
            { SyntaxKind.LiteralCharToken,             new Regex("\'")         },
            { SyntaxKind.LiteralStringToken,         new Regex("\"")         },
            { SyntaxKind.LiteralNumberToken,         new Regex("[0-9]")        },
            { SyntaxKind.OpenCurlyBracketToken,     new Regex("\\{")         },
            { SyntaxKind.CloseCurlyBracketToken,     new Regex("\\}")        },
            { SyntaxKind.OpenParenthesisToken,         new Regex("\\(")         },
            { SyntaxKind.CloseParenthesisToken,     new Regex("\\)")         },
            { SyntaxKind.OpenSquareBracketToken,     new Regex("\\[")         },
            { SyntaxKind.CloseSquareBracketToken,    new Regex("\\]")         },
            { SyntaxKind.CommaToken,                 new Regex(",")             },
            { SyntaxKind.EOLToken,                     new Regex("[\\r\\n]")     },
            { SyntaxKind.WhitespaceToken,             new Regex("\\s")         },
            { SyntaxKind.QuestionMarkToken,         new Regex("\\?")        },
            { SyntaxKind.PlusOperationToken,         new Regex("\\+")        },
            { SyntaxKind.MinusOperationToken,         new Regex("\\-")        },
            { SyntaxKind.MultiplyOperationToken,     new Regex("\\*")        },
            { SyntaxKind.PowerOperationToken,       new Regex("\\*\\*")     },
            { SyntaxKind.RootOperationToken,        new Regex("\\/\\/")     },
            { SyntaxKind.DivideOperationToken,         new Regex("\\/")        },
            { SyntaxKind.EqualToken,                 new Regex("==")            },
            { SyntaxKind.InEqualToken,              new Regex("!=")         }
        };


        static readonly SyntaxKind[] LiteralTokens =
        {
            SyntaxKind.EOLToken                 ,
            SyntaxKind.WhitespaceToken          ,
            SyntaxKind.QuestionMarkToken        ,
            SyntaxKind.ColonToken               ,
            SyntaxKind.SemiColonToken           ,
            SyntaxKind.CommaToken               ,
            SyntaxKind.OpenParenthesisToken     ,
            SyntaxKind.CloseParenthesisToken    ,
            SyntaxKind.OpenSquareBracketToken   ,
            SyntaxKind.CloseSquareBracketToken  ,
            SyntaxKind.OpenCurlyBracketToken    ,
            SyntaxKind.CloseCurlyBracketToken   ,
            SyntaxKind.PlusOperationToken       ,
            SyntaxKind.MinusOperationToken      ,
            SyntaxKind.MultiplyOperationToken   ,
            SyntaxKind.DivideOperationToken
        };

        /*
         * Implementing a generic tokenizer here
         * this might seem not standart, but im not following any standarts here. that would be boring wouldn't it
         */

        private bool MatchesPattern(Regex expression, int size = 1) => env.code.Length >= cursor + size && expression.IsMatch(env.code.Substring(cursor, size));

        private bool MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind kind, int size = 1) => MatchesPattern(Definitions[kind], size);


        public void Tokenize()
        {
            for (cursor = 0; cursor < env.code.Length;)
            {
                int savecursor = cursor;

                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.PowerOperationToken, 2))
                {
                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.PowerOperationToken, cursor, 2);
                    cursor += 2;
                    continue;
                }
                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.RootOperationToken, 2))
                {
                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.RootOperationToken, cursor, 2);
                    cursor += 2;
                    continue;
                }
                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.EqualToken, 2))
                {
                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.EqualToken, cursor, 2);
                    cursor += 2;
                    continue;
                }
                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.InEqualToken, 2))
                {
                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.InEqualToken, cursor, 2);
                    cursor += 2;
                    continue;
                }
                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.AccessorToken, 2))
                {
                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.AccessorToken, cursor, 2);
                    cursor += 2;
                    continue;
                }
                if (LiteralTokens.Any(n=>MatchesDefition(n)))
                {
                    MakeToken(LiteralTokens.First(n=>MatchesDefition(n)));
                    cursor++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.AssignmentToken,2))
                {
                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.AssignmentToken,cursor,2);
                    cursor+=2;
                    continue;
                }

                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.LiteralCharToken))
                {
                    int oldcursor = cursor;
                    do
                    {
                        cursor++;
                    }
                    while (MatchesPattern(Patterns["NumberPattern"]));
                    if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.LiteralCharToken))
                        MakeToken(SyntaxKind.LiteralCharToken,oldcursor,cursor - oldcursor + 1);
                    else
                        throw new ShirException.TokenizerException.CountNotTokenizeCharException($"char: {env.code.Substring(oldcursor, cursor - oldcursor + 1)} could not be tokenized");
                    cursor++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.LiteralStringToken))
                {
                    int oldcursor = cursor;
                    do
                    {
                        cursor++;
                    }
                    while (MatchesPattern(Patterns["StringPattern"]));
                    if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.LiteralStringToken))
                        MakeToken(SyntaxKind.LiteralStringToken, oldcursor, cursor - oldcursor + 1);
                    else
                        throw new ShirException.TokenizerException.CountNotTokenizeCharException($"char: {env.code.Substring(oldcursor, cursor - oldcursor + 1)} could not be tokenized");
                    cursor++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (MatchesDefition(SyntaxKind.LiteralNumberToken))
                {
                    int oldcursor = cursor;
                    do
                    {
                        cursor++;
                    }
                    while (MatchesPattern(Patterns["NumberPattern"]));

                    MakeToken(SyntaxKind.LiteralNumberToken, oldcursor, cursor - oldcursor);
                    continue;
                }

                if (MatchesPattern(Patterns["CharPattern"]))
                {
                    int oldcursor = cursor;
                    do
                    {
                        cursor++;
                    }
                    while (MatchesPattern(Patterns["NumCharPattern"]));
                    int len = cursor - oldcursor;

                    string TokenString = env.code.Substring(oldcursor, len);

                    if(Keywords.ContainsKey(TokenString))
                    MakeToken(Keywords[TokenString], oldcursor, len);
                    else
                    {
                        char nextchar = env.code[cursor];
                        if (nextchar == '(')
                            MakeToken(SyntaxKind.FunctionNameToken, oldcursor, len);
                        else
                            MakeToken(SyntaxKind.VariableNameToken, oldcursor, len);
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (savecursor == cursor)
                    throw new ShirException.TokenizerException.CountNotTokenizeCharException($"char: {env.code[cursor]} could not be tokenized");

                cursor++;
            }
        }


        public string AsCode()
        {
            return string.Join("",env.Tokens.Select(n=>n.GetValue()));
        }


        private void MakeToken(SyntaxKind type, int oldcursor, int length)
        {
            col += length;
            if (type == SyntaxKind.EOLToken)
            {
                line++;
                col = 0;
            }
            env.Tokens.Add(new Token(oldcursor, length, type, env,line,col));
        }


        private void MakeToken(SyntaxKind type, int length = 1)
        {
            col += length;
            if (type == SyntaxKind.EOLToken)
            {
                line++;
                col = 0;
            }
            env.Tokens.Add(new Token(cursor,length,type, env,line,col));
        }
    }
}
```

A Token:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ShirLanguageCompiler
{
    public enum SyntaxKind
    {
        // math operators
        PlusOperationToken,
        MinusOperationToken,
        DivideOperationToken,
        MultiplyOperationToken,
        PowerOperationToken,
        RootOperationToken,
        //boolean tokens
        EqualToken,
        InEqualToken,

        VariableNameToken,
        FunctionNameToken,


        // Variable type rokens
        NumberKeyword,
        BooleanKeyword,
        LetterKeyword,
        StringKeyword,

        // Function related rokens
        BindKeyword,
        ReturnKeyword,
        RefKeyword,
        ValKeyword,

        // Literal Values
        LiteralTrueKeyword,
        LiteralFalseKeyword,

        LiteralNumberToken,
        LiteralCharToken,
        LiteralStringToken,

        EOLToken,
        QuoteToken,
        ColonToken,
        SemiColonToken,
        CommaToken,
        QuestionMarkToken,
        WhitespaceToken,

        AssignmentToken,
        AccessorToken,

        OpenParenthesisToken,
        CloseParenthesisToken,

        OpenCurlyBracketToken,
        CloseCurlyBracketToken,

        OpenSquareBracketToken,
        CloseSquareBracketToken,
    }


    public class Token
    {
        ShirEnvironment env;
        public int start { get; private set; }
        public int length { get; private set; }
        public int line, col;
        public SyntaxKind type { get; private set; }
        public Token(int _start, int _length, SyntaxKind _type,ShirEnvironment _env,int line,int col) {
            this.start = _start;
            this.length = _length;
            this.type = _type;
            this.env = _env;
            this.line = line;
            this.col = col;
        }
        public string GetLocation() => $"<line:{line},col:{col}>";

        public override string ToString() => $"<{type}> start: {start} length: {length} value: {evaluate()}";
        public string evaluate() => $"'{Regex.Escape(env.code.Substring(start, length))}'";
        public string GetValue() => env.code.Substring(start, length); //type == SyntaxKind.EOLToken ? Environment.NewLine :
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are interested in some modern and non-traditional approaches to compiler design, I recommend you look at [Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/) (*Compilers Are Databases* [talk](https://youtu.be/WxyyJyB_Ssc), [slides](https://slideshare.net/Odersky/compilers-are-databases)), [Idris](http://idris-lang.org/) (and approaches to writing compilers in Haskell in general), [Nanopass compilers](http://nanopass.org/), and also the Roslyn C♯ compiler.

Comment: The complexer your language gets, the harder it will be to tokenize using Regex. Consider making your own InputStream and TokenStream with look-around and backtracking support.

Answer (score 15):

One small comment about your API.

> public void Tokenize()

I would expect a Tokenize method to return a stream (`IEnumerable`)  of `Token`s rather than modify state. This should be a pure and idempotent function in my opinion.

Comment: Youre probably right..I think the structure of my compiler is really wrong. I wish i could read up on it

Comment: This was one of the top hits when I googled for "compiler theory" http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/basics_lulu2.pdf

Answer (score 11):

Your code looks very clean and organized.

Only some comments (without understanding the code in depth)

- You would probably use the regex option `RegexOptions.Compiled` to improve performance
- The `Tokenize` method has lots of similar code fragments. You could use a list of `SyntaxKind` elements like you did with `LiteralTokens`.
- Here you call `MatchesDefition` twice:

> ```
> if (LiteralTokens.Any(n=>MatchesDefition(n)))
> {
>     MakeToken(LiteralTokens.First(n=>MatchesDefition(n)));
>     cursor++;
>     continue;
> }
> ```

It would be more performant to use the result from the first check like:

```
bool foundMatch = false;
foreach (var token in LiteralTokens)
{
    if (MatchesDefition(n))
    {
        MakeToken(token));
        cursor++;
        foundMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundMatch) { continue; }
```

Sure, it is not so elegant, but IMHO for a tokanizer performance comes before elegance. Probably there is also a better solution ;)

- You are using a dictionary (`Patterns`) to access the different patterns. Why not using variables? It is faster and you don't need to work with string to access them.
- The field `env` can be readonly

Realy just a few small remarks... overall it's a nice piece of code - good work :)

Comment: I think the answer from Nikita B will solve your point in a better way but an alternative to your solution would be: var x = LiteralTokens.FirstOrDefault(n=>MatchesDefition(n)); if(x != null) {...}

Comment: @NiklasJ: That was also my first thought. Unfortunately, `LiteralTokens` is an array of `SyntaxKind`s which are enums. Therefore the default value is the first value of the enum which is`SyntaxKind.PlusOperationToken`. It could be used, if the `SyntaxKind` enum will be extended by the value`SyntaxKind.None = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

A few other things:

1. `cursor += 2;` and `cursor++;` are all over the place in your `Tokenizer`. This looks very error-prone. You need a class that will move cursor automatically when you read a substring. Something similar to `StringReader`, but designed to better fit your task. Maybe:

   ```
   //instead of returning strings you can return a complex object, 
   //that would also hold information about columns, lines, etc.
   interface ICodeReader
   {
       //reads substring without moving `Position`
       string Peek(int count); 
       //reads substring and moves `Position` by `count`
       string Read(int count); 
       long Length { get; } //code length
       long Position { get; set; } //cursor

       //other members? 
   }
   ```
2. There is a lot of code repetition in `Tokenize` method, which boils down to "check if this string is a token of type X and parse it, if it is". This sounds like an interface to me:

   ```
    interface ITokenParser
    {
        bool CanParse(ICodeReader reader, ....);
        IEnumerable<Token> Parse(ICodeReader reader, ....)
    }
   ```

   implement one of those for every token (or every group of related tokens), and you should be able to rewrite `Tokenize` as:

   ```
    var parsers = new ITokenParser[] {...}; //should be a field
    var tokens = new List<Token>();
    while(reader.Position < reader.Length)
    {
        var parser = parsers.First(p => p.CanParse(reader, ...));
        tokens.AddRange(parser.Parse(reader, ...));
    }
   ```

   You will also be able to easily unit test every `ITokenParser` in isolation, which is a major benefit.

Comment: Definitely a cool idea, i will see how i could implement such thing.

Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 6):

You can use verbatim strings to reduce the slash chaos:

```
{ SyntaxKind.RootOperationToken,        new Regex(@"\/\/")     },
```

You can also use [IReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent your dictionaries from being modified. The readonly flag tells that no one can write something like `Keywords = null` but currently it still can be modified, e.g. `Keywords.Clear();`.

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, SyntaxKind> Keywords = new Dictionary<string, SyntaxKind>()
```