# Compiler Tokenizer implementation in C# - follow-up

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler, lexical-analysis

**I have posted [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165636/compiler-tokenizer-implementation-in-c) question 2 days ago and got amazing feedback on it.**

Hands back to the keyboard, I believe I took the suggestions into account and improved the classes drastically. In this question, would love further criticism and suggestions in regard to my code logic and coding style.

The `TokenFactory` and `TokenParser`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ShirLanguageCompiler
{
    public class TokenParser
    {
        private Regex Pattern;
        private SyntaxKind Type;
        public bool CanParse(TokenFactory factory) => Pattern.IsMatch(factory.UpcomingCode);

        public Token Parse(TokenFactory factory)
        {
            Match match = Pattern.Match(factory.UpcomingCode);

            return new Token(factory.Position, match.Length, factory.Location, Type, match.Value);
        }
        public TokenParser(Regex pattern, SyntaxKind type)
        {
            this.Pattern = pattern;
            this.Type = type;
        }
    }
    public class TokenFactory
    {
        private int Length { get; }
        private string Code { get; set; }

        public int Position { get; set; }
        public (int Line, int Column) Location;
        public string UpcomingCode => this.Code.Substring(Position);

        TokenParser[] Parsers = {
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^""(?:\\""|[^""])*""",  RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.LiteralStringToken        ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^'(?:\\'|[^'])+'",      RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.LiteralCharToken          ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^d\d+",                 RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.LiteralNumberToken        ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^false",                RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.LiteralFalseKeyword       ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^true",                 RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.LiteralTrueKeyword        ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^:",                    RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.ColonToken                ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^;",                    RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.SemiColonToken            ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\s",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.WhitespaceToken           ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^[\r\n]+",              RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.EOLToken                  ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^,",                    RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.CommaToken                ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^->",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.AccessorToken             ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^=>",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.AssignmentToken           ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\(",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.OpenParenthesisToken      ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\)",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.CloseParenthesisToken     ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\{",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.OpenCurlyBracketToken     ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\)}",                  RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.CloseCurlyBracketToken    ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\[",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.OpenSquareBracketToken    ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\]",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.CloseSquareBracketToken   ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\?",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.QuestionMarkToken         ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\+",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.PlusOperationToken        ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\-",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.MinusOperationToken       ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\*}",                  RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.MultiplyOperationToken    ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\*\*",                 RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.PowerOperationToken       ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\/",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.DivideOperationToken      ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\/\/",                 RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.RootOperationToken        ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^==",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.EqualToken                ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^!=",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.InEqualToken              ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^letter",               RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.LetterKeyword             ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^number",               RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.NumberKeyword             ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^boolean",              RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.BooleanKeyword            ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^str",                  RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.StringKeyword             ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^bind",                 RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.BindKeyword               ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^return",               RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.ReturnKeyword             ),

            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^ref",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.RefKeyword               ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^val",                   RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.ValKeyword               ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\D\w+\(\)",             RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.FunctionNameToken        ),
            new TokenParser(new Regex(@"^\D\w+",                RegexOptions.Compiled),SyntaxKind.VariableNameToken        )
        };


        public TokenFactory(string code)
        {
            this.Code = code;
            this.Length = code.Length;
            this.Position = 0;
            this.Location = (0, 0);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Token> GetTokenStream()
        {
            while(this.Position < this.Length)
            {
                TokenParser Parser = Parsers.First(n => n.CanParse(this));
                Token Parsed = Parser.Parse(this);
                if (Parsed.Type == SyntaxKind.EOLToken)
                    this.Location = (this.Location.Line++,0);
                else
                    this.Location.Column += Parsed.Length;
                this.Position += Parsed.Length;

                #if DEBUG
                    Console.Write(Parsed);
                #endif
                    yield return Parsed;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here the `Token` class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ShirLanguageCompiler
{
    public enum SyntaxKind
    {
        PlusOperationToken,
        MinusOperationToken,
        DivideOperationToken,
        MultiplyOperationToken,
        PowerOperationToken,
        RootOperationToken,

        EqualToken,
        InEqualToken,

        VariableNameToken,
        FunctionNameToken,

        NumberKeyword,
        BooleanKeyword,
        LetterKeyword,
        StringKeyword,

        BindKeyword,
        ReturnKeyword,
        RefKeyword,
        ValKeyword,

        LiteralTrueKeyword,
        LiteralFalseKeyword,

        LiteralNumberToken,
        LiteralCharToken,
        LiteralStringToken,

        EOLToken,
        QuoteToken,
        ColonToken,
        SemiColonToken,
        CommaToken,
        QuestionMarkToken,
        WhitespaceToken,

        AssignmentToken,
        AccessorToken,

        OpenParenthesisToken,
        CloseParenthesisToken,

        OpenCurlyBracketToken,
        CloseCurlyBracketToken,

        OpenSquareBracketToken,
        CloseSquareBracketToken
    }
    public interface IContainsLocation
    {
        (int Line, int Column) Location { get; set; }
        string LocationString { get; }
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("Value = {EscapedString} Start = {Start}, Length = {Length}, Location = {LocationString}")]
    public class Token: IContainsLocation
    {

        public int Start, Length;
        public (int Line, int Column) Location { get; set; }
        public SyntaxKind Type { get; private set; }
        public string InnerValue { get; private set; }

        public string LocationString
        {
            get
            {
                return $"(Line:{this.Location.Line},Collumn:{this.Location.Column})";
            }
        }
        public string EscapedString
        {
            get
            {
                return Regex.Escape(InnerValue);
            }
        }
        public Token(int start, int length, (int Line, int Column) Location, SyntaxKind type, string innervalue)
        {
            this.Start = start;
            this.Length = length;
            this.Type = type;
            this.InnerValue = innervalue;
            this.Location = Location;
        }

        public override string ToString() => this.InnerValue;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by replacing the tuple `(int Line, int Column) location` with an immutable struct named SourceLocation.

Here are some of the reasons why I would do this.

1. The concept already exists in several places. *TokenFactory*, *Token*, and *IContainsLocation* know about this tuple. Adding a FileName field to the tuple would require changes to all three types.
2. *TokenParser* and *Token* should not be modifying the contents of this tuple.
3. *TokenFactory* modifies its Location field but it is easy to change the interface so that it doesn't need to.
   Replace
   `public (int Line, int Column) Location;`
   with
   `public int Line {get; private set;}`
   `public int Column {get; private set;}`
   [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) gives a detailed explanation of why you should avoid using public fields.
4. Mutable tuples are a relatively new idea and there isn't a consensus on whether they are appropriate to use in APIs. I use them only in types that are internal or private.

Here is how I would write SourceLocation. I used ReSharper to generate the overrides and the IEquatable implementation.

```
    public struct SourceLocation : IEquatable<SourceLocation>
    {
        public int Line { get; }

        public int Column { get; }

        public SourceLocation(int line, int column)
        {
            Line = line;
            Column = column;
        }

        public bool Equals(SourceLocation other)
        {
            return Line == other.Line && Column == other.Column;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            return obj is SourceLocation && Equals((SourceLocation) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (Line * 397) ^ Column;
            }
        }

        public void Deconstruct(out int line, out int column)
        {
            line = Line;
            column = Column;
        }
    }
```

**TokenParser**

- Pattern and Type should both be marked readonly.
- Your code currently evaluates each regular expression twice.
  Consider changing the interface to something like this:
  `public bool TryParse(TokenFactory factory, out Token token)`
- *TokenParser* knows more about *TokenFactory* than it needs to.
  If you change the signature of TryParse to the following then you can test it independently of *TokenFactory*.
  `public bool TryParse(int position, string input, SourceLocation location, out Token token)`
  This would make it easier to write unit tests for the different SyntaxKinds and run them on every build.

**Token**

- This class seems like it could be made immutable without any loss in functionality.
- You can make *Token* immutable by replacing the public fields with get-only properties, removing all other property setters, and sealing the class.  Immutability eliminates the need to reason about what state an object is in. The article [Functional C#: Immutability](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/02/functional-c-immutability/) discusses this topic in detail.

Comment: Great suggestions and articles to read up on, thank you!